# problem with the installation of ghcjs-dom: out of memory installing jsaddle-dom

Tags: javascript, haskell, cabal, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

I have tried to install ghcjs-dom both with cabal or stack and I can't exclude jsaddle-dom. In particular, by making "stack build", it tries to install also jsaddle-dom, but my OS goes out of memory during the process. How can i fix it?
The ReadMe tells to do the following:

[image]

but I can't do it.

Compiling with cabal (cabal build) the error is:

[image]

While if I compile (stack build) with stack the error is:

[image]

My .cabal has the following build-depends:

```
 build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , ghcjs-dom ==0.9.4.0
    , haskell-src-exts >=1.23.1
    , mtl >=2.2.2
```

Comment: How much memory do you have? `ld` can use several gigabytes linking larger haskell libraries.

Comment: 6 Gb of Ram. I'm trying to expand the swap memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem: the linker needs a lot of Ram to build jsaddle, so the solution is to increase the swap memory (15 Gb needed).